# running sprinkler wire and power in same conduit?

Tags: electrical

can i run the sprinkler valve control wires in a 3/4 PVC conduit along with one set #12 wire to a single outlet approx 12 feet

Comment: Is the entire network of sprinkler wires also in conduit or other  wiring method which is appropriate for mains wiring? No fair popping out in loose wires or something.   Also, is the receptacle related to the sprinklers?

Answer (score 1):

From an NEC standpoint, the main deciding factor about running different voltages in the same conduit is that the conductor insulation must have the same voltage rating on all wiring. Standard residential insulation is 600V so the control wiring must have the same rating. Low voltage wiring usually are rated at 300V. So needless to say this would not be allowed.

Keep in mind I am not saying this is a good installation. There are many other reason why I would not like your installation. I am just saying it could be done if it made the above requirements.

Good luck

Comment: Actually, the rule is that all conductors must have insulation that is at a MINIMUM, the highest voltage in the circuit. So since that will be 120V or at worst, 240V, if both wires were rated for 300V it would be fine. NEC 300.3(C)(1). "All conductors shall have an insulation rating equal to at least the maximum circuit voltage applied to any
conductor within the enclosure, cable, or raceway." The end result may be the same however, because SOME sprinkler control wire is rated for "Low Voltage" use only, i.e. 50V or less.